# C# How to setup generic template based method mock

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, moq

I was wondering if there is any way to setup a generic template based method as mock method

```
var mockContext = new Mock<ICommunityContext>();
mockContext.Setup(c => c.Set<User>()).Returns(mockSet.Object);
```

On the other side in service, I'm trying to access this set as following

```
// Definition of Generic Service looks like following
public class Service<T> : IService where T : Entity

// Definition of User Service looks like following
public class UserService : Service<User> where T : Entity
```

And one of the function in Service is trying to do that, but it always return null

```
var user = Context.Set<T>().FirstOrDefault();
```

But following works

```
var user = Context.Set<User>().FirstOrDefault();
```

So, the question is "How to setup generic template based methods which works later with just simple T where T is template type of the object"